# Data from PostgreSQL sql not all inserting to another Sql Server DB

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have to manually push data from my django app to be inserted on another DB which using using another desktop application . Nearlly all the data saved on my postgress db for that particular id is inserted on that other DB  .

But it seems only one data is missing. Could it be that i have not set any Connection timeout on my setting.py file fro my DB .

Comment: No, it sounds like a programming error. Maybe the old "fence post problem".

Comment: only two data are not going through to that db VIA XML ... these are data where the user has to select dates so only one or two are not going through .